# when using the \balance to balance the references on the last page, somehow there is a blank line at the top of the second column

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

When using the \balance to balance the references on the last page, somehow there is a blank line at the top of the second column. There are the codes I use to generate the references.

\bibliographystyle{Bibliography/IEEEtran}
\balance
\bibliography{Bibliography/IEEEabrv,Bibliography/reliabilityboost}
[image]

And if I don't use the '\balance', the reference will not be arranged in the order.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP found the problem and summarized the solution nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, my dear, I finally found the solution. All I need to do is just to delete the package{flushend}. In fact, I USED *twice package{flushend}* so when I first deleted the package{flushend}, I found it not worked and I thought it was not the cause. Not until now, I just realized that I added the package twice and I just delete one of them at the beginning.

So that is how the sad story goes...My suggestion for any other users who suffering the same/similar problem is staying away from package{flushend}. Besides, what is more important is that keep awaken/healthy! Don't try to solve the type of problems when it is late at night, otherwise, you may suffer more.